# Problem with apple login on firebase - Duplicate credential received. Please try again with a new credential

Tags: javascript, firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication, apple-sign-in

I'm getting the following error while trying to add a sign up with apple in my nodejs backend:

status: auth/missing-or-invalid-nonce
message: Duplicate credential received. Please try again with a new credential

Here is the code:

```
      const clientId = 'com.mybusiness';

      const { nonce: nonce } = await appleSignin.verifyIdToken(
        appleIdentityToken,
        {
          audience: clientId,
          ignoreExpiration: true,
        }
      );

      const hashedNonce: string = crypto
        .createHash('sha256')
        .update(nonce)
        .digest()
        .toString();

      const provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('apple.com');
      const credential: OAuthCredential = provider.credential({
        idToken: appleIdentityToken,
        rawNonce: hashedNonce,
      });

      const userCredential: UserCredential = await this.clientAuth.signInWithCredential(
        credential
      );
```

Comment: Same here, did you solve it?